# Changing Axis Values from STL Plot

Tags: r

I have data of one year sales and I am studying its seasonality. I have created a time series of my data, and then, I have used the function stl and I have plotted it.

I would like to change the values of the x-axis and put my own values. For doing that I have used the function par(xaxt="n") and then the function `axis(side=1,at...)`. I can remove the values (with the function par(xaxt="n"), but function `axis(side=1,at...)` is not working, I can´t see my own values.

Does anyone how to solve this problem?

This is my code:

```
stcf=ts(tcf$tc.Ventas,start=c(2015,1),frequency = 4)

modelstl<-stl(log(stcf),s.window="periodic")

par(xaxt="n")

plot(modelstl, xaxt = "n",yaxt = "n")

axis(side=1,at=1:12,labels=expression("Ene.15","Feb.15","Mar.15","Abr.15","May.15", "Jun.15","Jul.15","Ag.15","Sep.15","Oct.15","Nov.15","Dic.15"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the xaxt parameter globally and the axis function is obeying it too. Therefore you are calling the axis like this:

```
axis(..., xaxt="n") # <-- the xaxt is implicit because of the par call before the plot
```

You can either remove the par call before the plot or add xaxt="s" to the axis call.

---

Another problem is that you are missing a quotation mark in the expression, it should be:

```
expression("Ene.15", "Feb.15", "Mar.15", "Abr.15", "May.15", "Jun.15", "Jul.15", "Ag.15", "Sep.15", "Oct.15", "Nov.15", "Dic.15")
```

The values given to expression are not evaluated, so as you are plotting, R tries to find the variable Jun.15 and it does not exist.

Alternatively you can use something like this to avoid shooting yourself in the foot:

```
c("Ene.15", "Feb.15", "Mar.15", "Abr.15", "May.15", "Jun.15", "Jul.15", "Ag.15", "Sep.15", "Oct.15", "Nov.15", "Dic.15")
```

Comment: Thanks @brni. But it still does not work! The axis function is not being evaluated.

Comment: I've modified my answer to help with the issue